# PHPMD @bin_dir@ error

Tags: php, jenkins, jenkins-cli, phpmd

I try to install PHPMD on Windows computer using the comments below

```
$ git clone git://github.com/phpmd/phpmd.git
cd phpmd
$ git submodule update --init
$ php composer.phar install
```

After installed PHPMD, I am getting the below error when I am trying to use PHPMD on Windows command prompt

```
Could not open input file: @bin_dir@\phpmd
```

Any one can help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't know if you got your problem fixed, but I had the same issue today and found a solution that works for me.

You need to edit the last line in your phpmd.bat file. When installed it looks like this:

```
"%PHPBIN%" "@php_bin@\phpmd" %*
```

And you need to update the @php_bin@ part to reflect the path to your phpmd file. Could be something along the lines of:

```
"%PHPBIN%" "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\phpmd\src\bin\phpmd" %*
```